# Refrences in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, reference

I have used a reference in this code for `map<int ,int>` but when I don't use a reference, the map does not get filled recursively. I have already solved this problem but don't know why I need to use a reference when I already provided `map<int ,int>` as parameter. Can you illustrate in depth?

```
void util(Node* root,map<int,int> &m, int level) {
    if (!root) return;

    m[level]+=root->data;

    util(root->right,m,level);

    util(root->left,m,level+1);
}

void diagonalSum(Node* root) {
    map<int,int> m;

    util(root,m,0);
    // cout<<m.size();
    for(auto i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++){
        cout<<i->second<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: If you pass by value, each function call will receive a *copy* of the map. Modifying a copy won't modify the original. Every decent tutorial, book or class should have included that information.

Comment: Start here: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: You would see the same problem without recursing.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't use a reference, you get a copy of the map when the function is called.

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607508/refrences-in-recursion#comment105378703_59607508): 
If you pass by value, each function call will receive a copy of the map. Modifying a copy won't modify the original.